# svg ripple effect to the circle tag/element

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-transitions, geometry

I am trying to apply the following animation to an svg circle element:

```
$color: #65ff78;

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle-ripple {
  background-color: #35ffc3;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: ripple 0.7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba($color, 0.3),
                0 0 0 1em rgba($color, 0.3),
                0 0 0 3em rgba($color, 0.3),
                0 0 0 5em rgba($color, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba($color, 0.3),
                0 0 0 3em rgba($color, 0.3),
                0 0 0 5em rgba($color, 0.3),
                0 0 0 8em rgba($color, 0);
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/FabienMotte/pen/gPKVxE

Changing the div to a circle did not work, as expected.

In the above codepen a div element has been used, but can I apply the same effect to an svg circle element?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: box-shadow is not a CSS property that has any effect on an SVG element. A CSS filter might work better depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to use a stack of circles instead of shadows. The radius of a `<circle>` is not CSS-animatable, so as a workaround you'll have to use a scale transformation. (A SMIL animation could work on the radius, but would not be compatible with Microsoft browsers.)

```css
rect {
  fill: #4e4e4e;
}
circle {
  fill: #65ff78;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
svg > circle:last-child {
  fill: #35ffc3;
  opacity: 1;
}
#rp1 {
  animation: ripple1 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(5.5);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(8.5);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
#rp2 {
  animation: ripple2 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(3.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(5.5);
  }
}
#rp3 {
  animation: ripple3 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(3.5);
  }
}
#rp4 {
  animation: ripple4 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple4 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%">
<defs>
  <g id="anims">
    <circle id="rp1" r="1em" />
    <circle id="rp2" r="1em" />
    <circle id="rp3" r="1em" />
    <circle id="rp4" r="1em" />
  </g>
</defs>
<rect height="100%" width="100%" />
<use xlink:href="#anims" x="50%" y="50%"/>
<circle r="0.5em" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation with reference from https://loading.io/spinner/ripple/-ripple-circle-scale-round-radar-radio

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: none; display: block; shape-rendering: auto;" width="281px" height="281px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
<defs>
        <g id="ripple-circle">
          <circle r="5" fill="none" stroke="#e92d2d" stroke-width="3">
            <animate
              attributeName="r"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              dur="1.5873015873015872s"
              values="0;15"
              keyTimes="0;1"
              keySplines="0 0.2 0.8 1"
              calcMode="spline"
              begin="0s"
            ></animate>
            <animate
              attributeName="opacity"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              dur="1.5873015873015872s"
              values="1;0"
              keyTimes="0;1"
              keySplines="0.2 0 0.8 1"
              calcMode="spline"
              begin="0s"
            ></animate>
          </circle>
          <circle r="5" fill="none" stroke="#e92d2d" stroke-width="3">
            <animate
              attributeName="r"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              dur="1.5873015873015872s"
              values="0;15"
              keyTimes="0;1"
              keySplines="0 0.2 0.8 1"
              calcMode="spline"
              begin="-0.7936507936507936s"
            ></animate>
            <animate
              attributeName="opacity"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              dur="1.5873015873015872s"
              values="1;0"
              keyTimes="0;1"
              keySplines="0.2 0 0.8 1"
              calcMode="spline"
              begin="-0.7936507936507936s"
            ></animate>
          </circle>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#ripple-circle" x="50" y="30" />

      <circle
        cx="50"
        cy="30"
        r="4"
        fill="#E92D2D"
        className="pointing-circle"
      />
</svg>
```