# How do I apply pulse circle animation to svg circle element in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, svg, pulse

I am trying to apply circle pulse animation to svg elements I have in react, like in this link:

https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/MaXxwv
or here:

https://codepen.io/riccardoscalco/pen/GZzZRz
or here:
[svg ripple effect to the circle tag/element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023922/svg-ripple-effect-to-the-circle-tag-element)

but they fail to do anything on my circles, or animate the circle in a manner which moves it and break the canvas

I tried to implement the css from these links, and also used  but it did not work for me

```
const ExamStageCircle = (props) => {
    const {xScale, yScale,index, node, colour} = props;

    const isActiveOrDone = node.done || node.active;

    return (
        <g>
            <circle  id="rp1" className="circle test-circle"
                key={index}
                cx={xScale(node.x)}
                cy={yScale(node.y)}
                r={node.r}
                fill={isActiveOrDone ? colour : "grey"}
            />
            {node.done ? 
                <text id="chk" x={xScale(node.x)-15} y={yScale(node.y)+12}>&#xf00c;</text>
                :
            node.active ? ''
                :
                <text id="chk" x={xScale(node.x)-10} y={yScale(node.y)+10}>&#xf023;</text>
            }

        </g>                    
    );
}
```

```css
circle {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

svg > circle:last-child {
    fill: #35ffc3;
    opacity: 1;
}
#rp1 {
    animation: ripple1 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple1 {
    0% {
        transform: scale(5.5);
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(8.5);
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
}
```

I expected the circles to have pulse animation but instead they break the UI:

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have more than one element with the same id value. That's not allowed.

Comment: After fixing the id-s please try adding `transform-origin: 50% 50%;  transform-box: fill-box;` for the animated circles

Comment: @enxaneta this looks much better but still not exactly what I need, this causes them to blink, not to have a ripple-pulse effect